# PHP - Old session variable on previous page (IE works fine!)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have a session variable `$_SESSION['name']`. I set in a php file which is called with `ajax` inside a `keyup` event. It works well. Until a user uses the previous page button.

When a user uses this button (or mouse button), the last set session variable value is basically not set. It will return to an older set value (the one before the last one). I wonder how/why and what I can do about it.

I've read quite a lot stackoverflow (and other) solutions, but nothing so far seems to work.

**HTML:**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="name" value="'.$_SESSION['name'].'">'
}

<script type="text/javascript" defer>
    $(function() {
        var name = $('input[name="name"]').val();

        $('input').on('keyup', function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'example.php?name=' + name,                
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    // blablabal more code
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**example.php:**

```
$_SESSION['name'] = 'test';
```

**Please note** I'm starting the session on all of my pages with `session_start();` and please note that I also tried to regenerate my session id with any hope that would do the trick.

Comment: Until you reload the "previous" page you will not see the updated session values because the page you're calling the PHP from has not had its session variables updated either.

Comment: @JayBlanchard but in IE, everything works fine. I'm currently testing in Chrome and here it does not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this you have to reload your page to see the changes.
although here is a suggestion to do this what you want to achieve.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
echo '<input type="text" name="name" value="'.$_SESSION['name'].'">'
 }

   <script type="text/javascript" defer>
    $(function() {
    var name = $('input[name="name"]').val();

    $('input').on('keyup', function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'example.php?name=' + name,                
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
               $("[name='name']").val('Your response');
            }
    });
});
```

By doing this you can achieve what you are looking for. also if you load the page it will get the value from session

Comment: This seems legit! I'm going to try this